# Does the limit $\frac{f(x_0 + \varepsilon) - f(x_0 - \varepsilon) -2 \varepsilon f'(x_0)}{\varepsilon^3}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f \in C^3(\mathbb{R})$, does the following limit exist

$$ \underset{\varepsilon 
\to 0}{\lim} \frac{f(x_0 + \varepsilon) - f(x_0 - \varepsilon) - 2 \varepsilon f'(x_0)}{\varepsilon^3}?
$$

It's been a while since I took Calculus and somehow I fail to see how I should approach this.

Comment: Does it exist when $f(x)=x$?

Comment: @geetha290krm you're right, but it seems like I forgot a factor of 2 in there that would at least impede this counterexample

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thanks, that's the trick I needed. If you post an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By applying Taylor's Theorem with Peano's Form of Remainder, we get that

$f(x_0\!+\!\varepsilon)=f(x_0)\!+\!\varepsilon f’(x_0)\!+\!\varepsilon^2\dfrac{f’’(x_0)}{2!}\!+\!\varepsilon^3\dfrac{f’’’(x_0)}{3!}\!+\!o\!\left(\epsilon^3\right)$

$f(x_0\!-\!\varepsilon)=f(x_0)\!-\!\varepsilon f’(x_0)\!+\!\varepsilon^2\dfrac{f’’(x_0)}{2!}^\!-\!\varepsilon^3\dfrac{f’’’(x_0)}{3!}\!+\!o\!\left(\epsilon^3\right)$

where $\,o\!\left(\varepsilon^3\right)\,$ represents a function such that $\,\lim_\limits{\varepsilon\to0}\dfrac{o\!\left(\varepsilon^3\right)}{\varepsilon^3}=0\,.$

Therefore ,

$\lim_\limits{\varepsilon\to0}\dfrac{f(x_0+\varepsilon)-f(x_0-\varepsilon)-2\varepsilon f'(x_0)}{\varepsilon^3}=$

$=\lim_\limits{\varepsilon\to0}\dfrac{2\varepsilon^3\dfrac{f’’’(x_0)}{3!}+o\!\left(\varepsilon^3\right)}{\varepsilon^3}=$

$=\lim_\limits{\varepsilon\to0}\left[\dfrac{f’’’(x_0)}3+\dfrac{o\!\left(\varepsilon^3\right)}{\varepsilon^3}\right]=\dfrac{f’’’(x_0)}3\,.$

It is not necessary that $\,f\in C^3(\mathbb{R})\,,\,$ but it is sufficient that $\,f’’’(x_0)\,$ exists.

It means that if $\,f’’’(x_0)\,$ exists, then

$\lim_\limits{\varepsilon\to0}\dfrac{f(x_0+\varepsilon)-f(x_0-\varepsilon)-2\varepsilon f'(x_0)}{\varepsilon^3}=\dfrac{f’’’(x_0)}3\,.$